# debug sql syntax, error #1064

Tags: mysql, syntax, phpmyadmin

I'm using the following script from phpmyadmin in a shared hosting:

```
USE newmakerting
CREATE TABLE `nemarketing_registration`.`users` (

`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`email` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`firstName` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`lastName` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`profession` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`company` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`country` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`ticketNumber` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`jobArea` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`networkingPeople` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`topics_networking` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`topics_research` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`topics_tochat` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`last_book` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
 PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) 
 ) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

But I got the following error:

```
# 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the handbook That corresponds

to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CREATE TABLE `` 

nemarketing_registration. `Users` (`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INC 'at line 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add delimieter after `USE newmakerting`, try

```
USE newmakerting;         -- << this one

CREATE TABLE `nemarketing_registration`.`users` 
(
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`email` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`firstName` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`lastName` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`profession` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`company` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`country` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`ticketNumber` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`jobArea` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`networkingPeople` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`topics_networking` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`topics_research` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`topics_tochat` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`last_book` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
 PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) 
 ) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```

Comment: Run! thanks but now I got a new error: #1044 - Access denied for user 'nmadmin'@'10.%' to database 'newmakerting'

Comment: meaning, the `user` you are using to connect on the server doesn't have enough privilege to access or alter the database.

Comment: I check the privileges of the user in the database and are all activated :/

Comment: use this comment 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON database_name TO user@host IDENTIFIED BY 'password';'
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

Comment: Using shared hosting is a headache, I ended up creating a graphical table in phpmyadmin, thanks for your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please change as per below :
1) "USE newmakerting" => "USE newmakerting;"
   Here semicolon is missing.
2) "CREATE TABLE `nemarketing_registration`.`users`"  =>
    "CREATE TABLE `newmakerting`.`users`"
    Here database name is wrong .
ex:
USE newmakerting;
CREATE TABLE `newmakerting`.`users` (
`id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
`email` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`firstName` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`lastName` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`profession` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`company` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`country` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`ticketNumber` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`jobArea` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`networkingPeople` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`topics_networking` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`topics_research` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`topics_tochat` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
`last_book` VARCHAR( 256 ) ,
 PRIMARY KEY ( `id` ) 
 ) CHARACTER SET utf8;
```